# Using docker-volum or equivalent with Openshift

Tags: docker, kubernetes, openshift, docker-volume, kubernetes-pod

I'm new on Openshift.

I am working on a system to facilitate deployment of my tests server with openshift.
Previously, one colleague prepare 3 Dockers images to do that:
A main image with compiler. And some other images. For example a MQ client, and an Oracle DB client.

When we use Docker, the content of the repository of MQ client is mounted on a folder on host machine and the main image mount (same way) this folder too from the host machine: in one word: we user “docker volum”. Same things is done for the Oracle client.

Here is an image to explain :
[mounted path image with 100% Docker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2KYn.png)

When we connect ourselves to the Docker main images: we can go to the "/opt" folder, and we can see the files from the other contener, so we can see our clients (MQ, Oracle).
So, we can re-use the MQ client image for other projects.

I would like to deploy these 3 images as a Pod on Openshift, but the Openshift (or k8s) volums seems very different. In the pod, I want to do the same thing that I did wit Docker.

I try to use "hostpath", but It mount a folder from the "pod" to the docker image : so the folder is empty, and the files from the docker images are not available.

I am very new in the world of openshift, so:
Can someone say if what I want to do is possible?
In any case, is this a good idea? If not, what is the correct architecture to create my Pod? (One docker image with all ?)

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You should build a single _self-contained_ image; don't bind-mount libraries from the host into your container.  This is doubly true when you're running in a clustered system like Kubernetes, which will know how to pull Docker images on its own, but doesn't know about arbitrary extra host-system content.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/install_config/storage_examples/shared_storage.html)'s example of sharing NFS-share across two pods but it can easily be adapted to other shared storage (GlusterFS etc). It's not recommended but you can use [hostpath](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath) to share host's filesystem in case of single-node development/testing.